# Copy X amount of words to clipboard in word with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need a word macro that either highlights the first 2500 words so I can later copy them to an external application or to copy those 2500 words to the clipboard directly.

After some research I have been able to find examples of similar things but it starts copying when it finds a certain word and ends in another word, not by amount of words.

Any ideas on how to copy the first x amount of words?

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you're asking for a code solution, but provide no code, you're very unlikely to get an answer on here..! I'd recommend sharing what you have thus far, and how it fell short of doing what you wanted it to.

Comment: I know it's hard to get an answer without providing code of what I've done, but that's part of the problem, i don't know how to tell Word to select a word in a specific position> I know how to do this in python (select all text until it counts x amount of spaces)but unfortunately i have to stick to VBA in this one and I'm just lost here, sorry for that :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a small example of one would do this :

```
Sub HighlightFirst2500()

    counter = 0
    For Each w In ThisDocument.Words
        If w Like "*[0-z]*" Then
            counter = counter + 1
            If counter >= 2500 Then
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
        If counter = 1 Then
            w.Select
        Else
            Selection.Extend
        End If
        w.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
    Next w

    Selection.Copy

    MsgBox "The first " & counter & " words were highlighted in yellow AND added to the clipboard!"

End Sub
```

So basically,

1. For each **word** in this document
2. If it *LOOKS* like a word (or a number), **increment** the counter
3. Highlight the word and add it to the selection even if it doesn't look like a word
4. If the counter busts the limit, exit the loop **early**
5. Copy everything that is **selected**

Answer (score 0):

I see two options, 1 will take the first 2,500 words and put it in a string for you for later use in the code, the second option will just select and copy the first 2,500 words

```
Sub PutInVariable()
Dim MyArr As Variant, MyString As String
MyArr = Split(ThisDocument.Content.Text, " ")
ReDim Preserve MyArr(2499)
MyString = Join(MyArr, " ")
End Sub


Sub SelectAndCopy()
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=2500, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.Copy
End Sub
```